# Best tools for creating a REST API with static data

Tags: mongodb, rest, flask

I need some Tips for building a REST API with about 35000 static (non-changing) JSON data.

It's my first time building a REST API seriously, so I need some design decision advice.

First, I was planning to use Flask to build the API since I am familiar with it and MongoDB to store the data. But I've heard that MongoDB is not a good choice for data that do not change.

What I would like to know are:

1. Which DB is suitable for this kind of data?
2. Is Flask a good choice if I am expecting many users using the API at the same time?
3. What are the brief steps for doing this? What I have in my mind right now is something like below:

Steps:

```
1) Upload my data to DB
2) Create a REST API that helps the user fetch the data
3) Upload the REST API to some server
4) Test with Postman to see if it works
```

Is my overall thought correct?

Any advice would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are unsure about what DB to use I would just go with PostgreSQL.  It's scalable so if you ever need to build on your dataset it will work just fine.  In terms of performance it just depends on how many requests it gets, but I bet it could handle whatever you throw at it.

Regarding the API, if you are set with Flask then I recommend the package Flask-Restful.  Outline your db using an ORM in a file called models.py.  In a folder called resources, make files that serve as your API resources.  Example would be blogposts.py, which would have a get request for all or a single post, post, put, and delete for single posts.  Here is something I have for a really lightweight blog.  Using peewee as an ORM and another package called Flask-HTTPAuth for authentication.

```
# blogposts.py

import json

from flask import jsonify, Blueprint, abort, make_response
from flask_restful import (Resource, Api, reqparse, inputs, fields,
                               url_for, marshal, marshal_with)

from auth import auth
import models

blogpost_fields = {
    'id': fields.Integer,
    'title': fields.String,
    'content': fields.String,
    'created': fields.DateTime
}

def blogpost_or_404(id):
    try:
        blogpost = models.BlogPost.get(models.BlogPost.id==id)
    except models.BlogPost.DoesNotExist:
        abort(404)
    else:
        return blogpost


class BlogPostList(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.reqparse.add_argument(
            'title',
            required=True,
            help='No title provided',
            location=['form', 'json']
        )
        self.reqparse.add_argument(
            'content',
            required=False,
            nullable=True,
            location=['form', 'json'],
            default=''
        )
        super().__init__()

    def get(self):
        blogpost = [marshal(blogpost, blogpost_fields)
            for blogpost in models.BlogPost.select()]
        return {'BlogPosts': blogpost}

    @marshal_with(blogpost_fields)
    @auth.login_required
    def post(self):
        args = self.reqparse.parse_args()
        blogpost = models.BlogPost.create(**args)
        return (blogpost, 201, {
                'Location': url_for('resources.blogposts.blogpost', id=blogpost.id)
               })

class BlogPost(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.reqparse.add_argument(
            'title',
            required=False,
            help='No title provided',
            location=['form', 'json']
        )
        self.reqparse.add_argument(
            'content',
            required=False,
            nullable=True,
            location=['form', 'json'],
            default=''
        )
        super().__init__()

    @marshal_with(blogpost_fields)
    def get(self, id):
        return (blogpost_or_404(id))

    @marshal_with(blogpost_fields)
    @auth.login_required
    def put(self, id):
        args = self.reqparse.parse_args()
        try:
            blogpost = models.BlogPost.select().where(
                models.BlogPost.id==id).get()
        except models.BlogPost.DoesNotExist:
            return make_response(json.dumps(
                    {'error': 'That blogpost does not exist or is not editable'}
                ), 403)
        else:
            query = blogpost.update(**args).where(models.BlogPost.id==id)
            query.execute()
            blogpost = (blogpost_or_404(id))
            return (blogpost, 200, {
                'Location': url_for('resources.blogposts.blogpost', id=id)
               })

    @auth.login_required
    def delete(self, id):
        try:
            blogpost = models.BlogPost.select().where(
                models.BlogPost.id==id).get()
        except models.BlogPost.DoesNotExist:
            return make_response(json.dumps(
                    {'error': 'That blogpost does not exist or is not editable'}
                ), 403)
        else:
            query = blogpost.delete().where(models.BlogPost.id==id)
            query.execute()
            return '', 204, {'Location': url_for('resources.blogposts.blogposts')}


blogposts_api = Blueprint('resources.blogposts', __name__)
api = Api(blogposts_api)
api.add_resource(
    BlogPostList,
    '/blogposts',
    endpoint='blogposts'
)
api.add_resource(
    BlogPost,
    '/blogposts/<int:id>',
    endpoint='blogpost'
)
```

Resource classes have methods with the http method name, this is what sets which methods are allowed.  For instance, if I tried to delete to /blogposts without an ID, it would respond with method not allowed.  Delete is only defined for a single post.  Marshaling determines what information is in the response, you define it with blogpost_fields at the top. In the **init** of each class, we define the Request Parser which is what determines the information the API needs.  In this example we only need a title and the post content.  In a users resource you would add in things like email, username, password, verify password, admin status etc.

```
# models.py

import datetime

import jwt
from argon2 import PasswordHasher
from peewee import *

import config

DATABASE = PostgresqlDatabase('blogdb', user=config.DB['USER'], password=config.DB['PW'], host=config.DB['HOST'])
HASHER = PasswordHasher()


class User(Model):
    username = CharField(unique=True)
    email = CharField(unique=True)
    password = CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE

    @classmethod
    def create_user(cls, username, email, password, **kwargs):
        email = email.lower()
        try:
            cls.select().where(
                (cls.email==email)|(cls.username**username)
            ).get()
        except cls.DoesNotExist:
            user = cls(username=username, email=email)
            user.password = user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            return user
        else:
            raise Exception("User with that email or username already exists")

    @staticmethod
    def verify_auth_token(token):
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, config.SECRET_KEY)
            return payload['sub']
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            return 'Signature expired. Please log in again.'
        except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
            return 'Invalid token. Please log in again.'

    @staticmethod
    def set_password(password):
        return HASHER.hash(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return HASHER.verify(self.password, password)

    def generate_auth_token(self, id):
        try:
            payload = {
                'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=0, seconds=5),
                'iat': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
                'sub': id
            }
            return jwt.encode(
                payload,
                config.SECRET_KEY,
                algorithm='HS256'
            )
        except Exception as e:
            return e


class BlogPost(Model):
    title = CharField(default='', unique=True)
    content = TextField(default='')
    created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE

def initialize():
    DATABASE.connect()
    DATABASE.create_tables([User, BlogPost], safe=True)
    DATABASE.close()
```

```py
# auth.py

from flask import g

from flask_httpauth import HTTPTokenAuth

import models


auth = HTTPTokenAuth(scheme='Bearer')

@auth.verify_token
def verify_token(token):
    user = models.User.verify_auth_token(token)
    if user is not None:
        g.user = user
        return True
    return False
```

Models is pretty self explanatory if you've ever worked with an ORM like SQLAlchemy.  I would recommend that package since your dataset is far far far larger than the one for this example.  HTTPAuth allows you to decorate your API resource methods with a required authentication method.  In my example, logging in will generate a JWT which needs to be sent with each request as a Bearer token.

Once all of that is set up you register your API blueprints in app.py

```py
# app.py

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(users_api, url_prefix='/api/v1')
app.register_blueprint(blogposts_api, url_prefix='/api/v1')
app.register_blueprint(login_api)
```

That's it!